# Any tips for blocking an address range for outgoing packets?

Tags: network, firewall

Anyone used `ipfw` or `pfctl` to block an IP address range for outgoing packets?

I would like to temporarily block Apple's IP address range `17.*.*.*` to find everything that's phoning home phoning home.  Anyone know if Apple owns any other IP address ranges?

Comment: There's actually no "out" in ipfw. Technically, it's classified as "in" and "not-in." May be semantics, but there is a difference. I block traffic using inbound rules (e.g., to block FB, I use: `deny ip from 69.171.224.0/19 to any in`). If you're interested in isolated traffic, netstat is a better tool to look at. To my knowledge, Apple doesn't a) spy on their users, and b) they don't own the entire 17.0.0.0-17.255.255.255 block.

Comment: I might be wrong cksum, but I am pretty sure they DO actually own the entire 17 class A ip address range.

Comment: Apple does indeed own [17.everything](http://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-17-0-0-0-1), so you could use a rule like `deny ip from any to 17.0.0.0/8` to block all traffic to that.  However, that's not the *only* address range that Apple uses.  You might think about blocking apple.com at the DNS level instead/also.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend [Little Snitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html). Although it doesn't do anything you couldn't do with free tools, it makes monitoring, configuring, and blocking your system's outgoing traffic on a per-application basis ridiculously easy.

I'm a programmer, and one of those guys who always has a Terminal window open, and yet I *still* prefer using Little Snitch for this task.

It's not free, but it is cheap.  And the free trial is fully functional - the only caveat is you have to manually restart it every 3 hours.

That would probably be all you need to open all your Apple-branded apps and verify whether or not they're phoning the mothership.

And if they are phoning any address outside the 17.x.x.x range, you'd learn that really quick.

Comment: I would worry that a closed source tool like Little Snitch already ignores traffic it's authors deemed unimportant.  I've used Little Snitch's free version for evaluating non-Apple software before though.

Comment: +1 anyways, always good when people mention user friendly tools that help expose apps phoning home.